# Powershell script is not creating csv file when executed from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, output, export-to-csv

When I execute my powershell script from the command line I get the expected csv file output but when I execute from C# the csv output file is not generated.

## C# Code: (TestPWSScript)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace POC_UI_PWSExecution
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
    
            private void btnExecPWS001_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var ps1File = @"C:\project_source\pwsSandbox\test.ps1";
    
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "powershell.exe",
                    Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{ps1File}\"",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
        }
    }
```

## Powershell script: (test.ps1)

```
`Get-Process | Export-Csv -Path c:\test_results\processes.csv`
```

I have tested the powershell script from the command line and it works perfectly, creating the csv file.  Updated powershell script to specify folder name.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it’s not being created in another folder? What if you’re specific with the output file path?

Comment: Yes, I scanned my drive for the output file and nothing.  I have also updated the powershell script to output to a specific folder.

Comment: Try changing the -NoProfile and -ExecutionPolicy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3#profiles-and-execution-policy

Comment: Are you running the C code on the same machine? If not does the path exist where you're running it? i.e. c:\test_results\ - `Export-Csv` will create a file but not a folder.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done 1 of 2 methods - with or without the PowerShell SDK.

I usually use the PowerShell SDK, but that does require an additional library to be installed via Nuget.

I would instantiate the process separately, and pass the `ProcessStartInfo` into that separately, and hold off for the process to complete

### Option 1 (no SDK)

```cs
private void btnExecPWS001_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ps1File = @"C:\project_source\pwsSandbox\test.ps1";
    
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{ps1File}\"",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false;  //include this option, set to false
        CreateNoWindow = true;
    };

    // create a new process object and start
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    // then wait to exit
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

### Option 2 (with SDK)

1. Install PowerShell SDK with nuget:
   a. `dotnet add package Micrososft.PowerShell.SDK` , or
   b. **PM>** `Install-Package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`
2. Add the missing using statement: `using System.Management.Automation;`
3. Update your function:

```cs
private void btnExecPWS001_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // set the script path
    var ps1File = @"C:\project_source\pwsSandbox\test.ps1";

    // create powershell object
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // add ps1 script to object
        ps.AddScript($"& '{ps1File}'");

        // execute script
        IAsyncResult result = ps.BeginInvoke();

        // wait for script to complete
        while (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);  // wait 1/10th second and check again
        }
    }
}
```